# CSS element disables page href links

Tags: html, css

I found a fun CSS star-field simulation for a HTML page back ground. When I added it to my page document, the exiting href bookmarks and external links are disabled.

I tried to find a solution on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/we7d6qua/

The test bookmark jumps down the page. When you comment out the animation element (HTML lines 7-13) the link is enabled. Not quite sure why this animation disables the links.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

I've tried reordering the location of the animation. Doesn't make a difference. If animation is included links don't work.

This is the minimum example on JSfiddle

```
<html>

  <br>
  <br>
 
  <div id="space">
    <div class="stars"></div>
    <div class="stars"></div>
    <div class="stars"></div>
    <div class="stars"></div>
    <div class="stars"></div>
  </div>
  
  div>
    <p style=color:orange;background-color:green;text-align:center;font-size:55px;>Page Title</p>
    <p style=color:white;text-align:center;font-size:25;>this is what it's about</p>
    <br> <br>
    <p style=color:orange;text-align:center;font-size:35;>I can add a link right <a href="#new_section">Here</a></p>
  </div>
  <br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br>
  
  <p style=color:orange;text-align:center;font-size:35;>this is a bookmark</p>
  
  
  
  <a id="new_section">new section</a>
</html>type here
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

/* Stars 
------------------------------------- */

#space, .stars {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;                                                                                     z-index: 99;                              
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.stars {
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 30px, #eee, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 40px 70px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 50px 160px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 90px 40px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 130px 80px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 160px 120px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  animation: zoom 5s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  z-axis: 1;
}

.stars:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.stars:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 20% 60%;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.stars:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: -20% -30%;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.stars:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: 40% -80%;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.stars:nth-child(5) {
  background-position: -20% 30%;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  } 
  85% {
    opacity: .75;
    transform: scale(2.8);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(3.5);
  }
}

type here
```

Comment: there is a `z-index: 99;` in the line 12 where `bottom: 0` is defined. that is pushing the element over the text. use `z-index: -1`

Comment: Also `z-axis` is not a thing

Comment: removed those problem still exist

Comment: z-index: -1; fixes the issue! Thanks @Sysix

Answer (score 1):

`#space` and `.stars` have their position set to:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 99;
```

That is, place them on top of everything else (`z-index`) and let them cover the whole viewport (`top,bottom,left,right` set to `0`). Fix them starting at the top (`position:absolute`).

These `<div>`s will therefore lie on top of your page, at least until the fold (i.e. the part visible without scrolling). They are literally on top of all your links there.

To re-enable the links you need to get them out of the way for mouse clicks. The easiest way to achieve this with the current code is with this addition to the CSS:

```css
#space, .stars {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```